# How to retrieve Salesforce reports (in a subfolder) using VS Code

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin, visualstudiocode, mdapi

How can we retrieve SF reports in visual studio code, I have tried below options:

1).  Using manifest.xml -> Nothing happened, no reports extracted and no error shown either.

2). Using sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Report:folder1/reportAPIName1:
this is working fine but one report at a time.

Also, please advise, if there is a way to retrieve reports in the same format what we get using ANT(metadata API).
Our CI/CD tools are still using mdapi's.

thanks in advance.